# drupal_get_path function for third party PHP includes files

Tags: 7

I am trying to add some PHP includes files into Drupal 7 site. The files are on this page - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/connecting_to_the_api_using_php.htm under the "Required PHP Includes" heading. It looks like I need these files: **soap-wsse.php**, **exacttarget_soap_client.php**, **xmlseclibs.php** in my Drupal install.

I will need to use the require('exacttarget_soap_client.php') function in a Drupal custom module.

My question is where to place these files in the file structure of Drupal and what would be the $type using drupal_get_path() function? Should I be using the Libraries API instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`drupal_get_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7.x) returns the path of a module, a theme, a theme engine, or a profile. It's not for loading a generic PHP file, for which you need [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x) which (despite the name) can be used for a PHP file that can be loaded with `require_once`.

Supposing you add the *soap-wsse.php* file in the *includes* directory of the *test_module* module, you cal load that file using the following code.

```
module_load_include('php', 'test_module', 'includes/soap-wsse');
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added the file to the code. I have added the following: ` $path = module_load_include('php', 'mc_forms', 'includes/exacttargetsoap/exacttarget_soap_client'); require($path . 'exacttarget_soap_client.php');`

Comment: Do I need to include path in require() function? The path for the module I am referencing is in the following folders: sites > all > modules > custom > mc_forms. Do I just add 'mc_forms' or 'custom/mc_forms' ? Thanks.

Comment: I am currently getting the error - ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'CloudSoapClient' (T_STRING) in module_load_include() . Is this am issue with the require() function?

Comment: `module_load_include()` loads the file. You don't need to use the value returned from the function, nor use `require`. `module_load_include()` just needs the name of the module, not the directory containing it. Drupal will find where the module is installed, if it's installed.

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.2.3 or higher?

Comment: If you are using the code given as example in [Connecting to the API using PHP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/connecting_to_the_api_using_php.htm) (the page you linked), I  think there is a syntax error in `@$client = new Marketing CloudSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));`.

Comment: Okay. thank you. It is PHP 7.1.13. I will check on the syntax error.